# Pandas - Filter data frame with another data frame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, filter

I have two data frames that have same length like this

```
df1: 
   density
1  1,45
2  3,87
3  4,35
4  2,87
5  0.74
6  9.34
7  3.087
8  0.28
9  6,47
10 5,59
```

The second data frame looks like this

```
df2:
  State
1  1
2  1
3  1
4  1
5  1
6  1
7  0
8  0
9  0
10 0
```

I want an output that looks like this which means filter df1 in order to keep only values where df2 is equal to 1 :

```
output: 
   density
1  1,45
2  3,87
3  4,35
4  2,87
5  0.74
6  9.34
```

How can I do that?
Can you help me please.

Comment: df1[df2.eq(1).values] ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let's use boolean index:

```
df1[df2.eq(1).values]
```

Output:

```
  density
1    1,45
2    3,87
3    4,35
4    2,87
5    0.74
6    9.34
```

Comment: @piRSquared Still confused which is my answer and which is Scott's

Answer (score 5):

This should work

```
df1[df2.State.astype(bool)]
```